# A python function to extract data within a griddata plot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following code and plot:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:200j, 0:1:200j]
rng = np.random.default_rng()
points = rng.random((1000, 2))
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])
grid_z = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
plt.xlabel("Degrees")
plt.ylabel("Degrees")
plt.imshow(grid_z, extent=(-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5), origin='lower')
```

I want to extract the averaged value of all points within a circular area with radius of 0.25° centered within the above plot.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "extract data"? What's the expected output? Do you want an image with a null-values outside the circle?

Comment: Thanks for your questions, I want just the average value of all points within that circle.

Comment: Probably you should specify it directly in the original question.

Comment: What do you mean by "radius of 5°"? I thought you meant a radius of 5, but the grid defined in the code is a grid over the square [0, 1] x [0, 1] so it is completely included in a circle with radius 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful comments. I changed the code and the region of interest accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need is a boolean mask of your circle.
Then you can apply it to `grid_z` to isolate all the values inside the circle and compute their mean.

A better approach is to use the mask directly on `grid_x` and `grid_y` to interpolate the function only on the needed points.

```
# Compute the mask of a circle
center_grid_x = 0.5
center_grid_y = 0.5
radius = 0.25
mask = (grid_x - center_grid_x) ** 2 + (grid_y - center_grid_y) ** 2 < radius **2

# The mask can be visualized with 
# plt.imshow(mask)

# Apply the mask to grid_z and compute the mean
mean1 = np.mean(grid_z[mask])

# Or better compute only the values of points inside the circle
values_z = griddata(points, values, (grid_x[mask], grid_y[mask), method='linear')
mean2 = np.mean(values_z)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was looking for!